# prestashop 1.6 add (upload file) field to category

Tags: file-upload, field, prestashop, add-in

Hi, I have a problem adding **upload file field** to category (admin).
    This is what I have done:
    copy */controllers/admin/AdminCategoriesController.php* >> */override/controllers/admin/*
    inside I've deleted everything except **renderForm()** function so my code looks like:

```
    class AdminCategoriesController extends AdminCategoriesControllerCore
    {
        public function renderForm()
        {
            everything from original file
            ...
            return AdminController::renderForm();
        }
    }
```

So and my point(question) is:
    What should I put in

```
$this->fields_form = array(...

    'input' => array(
HERE
```

I've tryed this:

```
    array(
      'type' => 'file',
      'label' => $this->l('File'),
      'name' => 'new_file',
      'file' => isset($link) ? $link : null,
      'size' => isset($size) ? $size : null,
      'delete_url' => self::$currentIndex.'&'.$this->identifier.'='.$this->_category->id.'&token='.$this->token.'&deleteFile=1',
      'hint' => $this->l('Upload a file to category from your computer.'),
    ),
```

and before this I write(it was like this in AdminAttachmentsController.php):

```
    if (($obj = $this->loadObject(true)) && Validate::isLoadedObject($obj))
      {
        $link = $this->context->link->getPageLink('category', true, NULL, 'id_category='.$obj->id);
```

`if (file_exists(_PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_.$obj->file))
    $size = round(filesize(_PS_CAT_IMG_DIR_.$obj->file) / 1024);
}

But it won't copy the file on server ...
Thank for any answers.`